# How do I get rid of the part of an object which can't be seen in edit mode?

Tags: mesh

I am really new to Blender, sorry if my question is stupid.
How do I get rid of the straight one? Both "rods" are part of the same object I think.
However, I see no trace of the straight rod when I go into edit mode.
(except for the really small orange dot in the bottom of the straight rod, which appears in both edit and object mode)
*Please look at the images below*

[image: Two rods, which of one curved and the other straight]

[image: Same as the previous scene however the straight one's gone, and the curved one is replaced by multiple black dots]

Comment: The other part is probably hidden in edit mode.  Alt-h in 3D viewport, edit mode to unhide all; then x->vertices to delete selected.

Comment: Haha, I feel kinda dumb now. But thank you very much! (it worked)

Comment: Incidentally, the orange dot marks the origin of your object.